# Why does my dynamic array of string pointers cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I would like to hold a dynamic list of objects. I am not allowed to use VLAs, so I wrote the following function: (Originally this was a list of structs I defined, but I reproduced the same problem with strings.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void appendSeq(char ** seq, char *** seqList, size_t curSeqListSize) {
    if (*seqList == NULL)
        *seqList = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));
    else
        *seqList = (char **) realloc(*seqList, sizeof(char *) * (curSeqListSize + 1));
    if (*seqList == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    *seqList[curSeqListSize] = *seq;
}

int main()
{
    char *curSeq = "";
    char ** seqList = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        curSeq = "Sequence";
        char* curSeqCopy = strdup(curSeq);
        appendSeq(&curSeqCopy, &seqList, i);
    }
}
```

This fails with a segmentation error, and it seems that the realloc() function is not doing its job - Why?

Comment: where does it fail

Comment: when you step through what value of i is the last value before it segfaults, what line does it segfault, what are the values of the params when it segfaults.

Comment: `*seqList[curSeqListSize]` ==> `(*seqList)[curSeqListSize]`. And fyi, you never adjust `curSeqListSize`, which ideally would be passed by pointer as well and updated accordingly for the caller.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @WhozCraig That solves it, thanks! If you'd like to post an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your a victim of failing to understand [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). In C, `[]` has higher precedence than `*`, so this:

```
*seqList[curSeqListSize] = ...
```

says "find the `curSeqListSize`  slotted `char**` in the sequence of `char**` pointed to by `seqList`, then dereference *that*. That's wrong. You need to shove higher precedence in to your `seqList` expression, and `()` will do that:

```
(*seqList)[curSeqListSize] = ...
```

says "Get the `char**` pointed to by `seqList`, then get the `curSeqListSize` slotted `char*` from that.

I'd change a number of other things, but that's where your wheels fell off the wagon.